# Django - PubSub or workflows or combined?

Tags: django, events, workflow, publish-subscribe, pipeline

I am building a chemistry application with django that focuses on reactions. It bonds an atom to an existing molecule. The reaction **event** triggers a bunch of (a) **validations** to make sure the feasibility of the molecule checks out (b) **subsequent events** as the molecule

---

**Nested Functions:**

So I could have my logic layer just keep feeding Python functions into other Python functions, but my fear is that this will become a tangled mess quickly. I also want to have a record of the steps with success/fail and other basic stats, so one hanging process is probably not the best.

---

**PubSub:**

So I could have multiple functions that subscribe/ listen for a reaction and then run/ don't run based on criteria. Using something like [django-redis-pubsub](https://pypi.org/project/django-redis-pubsub/).

---

**Workflows:**

Enter [workflows](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html). I suppose I could structure the whole reaction process as a giant workflow which would have better transaction atomicity? Should I combine this approach with a pubsub?

```
rule NAME:
input:
    "path/to/inputfile",
    "path/to/other/inputfile"
output:
    "path/to/outputfile",
    "path/to/another/outputfile"
script:
    "path/to/script.py"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967398/python-based-asynchronous-workflow-modules-what-is-difference-between-celery-w